# how to return index from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array (x) of 10 values, and another array (y) with 100 values. 
8 of the values in x are contained in y and there are 2 values in x that for not in y.

what I want to do is to compute the distance between each of the values in y against each value in x and return the min value. 
Then return the closest value in y to the value in x and graph them and plot them.

This is an example of what I have got so far...

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1100,1200,10])
y = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)

D = spatial.distance_matrix(x.reshape(-1,1), y.reshape(-1,1))

min = np.min(D, axis=1)
```

How do I now return an array of the values in y that correspond to the values in min?

What I would like to be able to do is have an array z equal to the best y values used to minimise in np.min(D, axis=1) and arranged in the same order as x so i can then do the following

```
plt.scatter(x,z)
```

And compare how well all the values found match.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `argmin` : `idx = D.argmin(1)` and then use `idx` to filter-out/select off `y`?

Answer (score 0):

For searching indexes:

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
val = np.array([3,7,5,3])
index = [arr.tolist().index(i) for i in val]
index
```

but in your case, it will raise an error, because no matching values will be found.

Comment: Not to sure what this does... but Divakars suggestion helped! but thank you!